# Connection Manage File Throw Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

**Code-1**  : (working fine)

```
package com.connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class SqlServerJDBC {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
        String server,user,password,database;
        int port;
        String jdbcUrl;

        server="admin-PC";
        port =1433;
        user="sa";
        password="Admin@123";
        database="ORDD_LOGIN_DB";

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("#- driver load");
        jdbcUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://"+server+":"+port+";user="+user+";password="+password+";databaseName="+database+";";
        System.out.println("CONstring="+jdbcUrl); 

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
        System.out.println("# - CONNECTION OBTAINED");


        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("# - STATMENT OBTAINED");

        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from UserInfo;");
        System.out.println("# - query executed");

        if (rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("output colume = "+rs.getString(1));
        }

        rs.close();stmt.close();con.close(); System.out.println("resource relised......done");



    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

}
```

---

**Code-2**  (Not Working)

```
package com.connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class SqlServerJDBC {

public static Connection getconnection() {
    Connection con = null;

    try
    {
        String server,user,password,database,jdbcUrl;
        int port;
        server="admin-PC";port =1433;user="sa";password="Admin@123";database="ORDD_LOGIN_DB";

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("#- driver load");

        jdbcUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://"+server+":"+port+";user="+user+";password="+password+";databaseName="+database+";";
        System.out.println("CONstring="+jdbcUrl); 

         con=DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
        System.out.println("# - CONNECTION OBTAINED");



    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    System.out.println(con);
    return con;
}
}
```

**Error Massage:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver null java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Can you post full stack trace? I guess you have an exception on `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")` call, right? Make sure you have JDBC driver jar on your classpath

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDrivernull
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Do you run both classes under the same environment and classpath?

Comment: yes both are running under same environment... but the code-1 is working fine.

Comment: So do you see results from the DB printed to the console if you use Code-1? Code-2 doesn't have `main` method. How do you run your  applications?

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing it, but I can't see any difference in your code apart from the whitespace until after you have obtained a connection,

Comment: yes i see the code1 is print the result to console. i tried code2 with the my same application (web o)

Comment: HI mark Rotteveel  your right i copied as it is and to connection manager class which return connection.